# Hibernate-OGM-MongoDB: how to create/update collections on start-up?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to configure Hibernate-OGM for MongoDB in a Spring-Boot application, but it is not creating the corresponding collections in the DB running locally.

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.phishbowl</groupId>
    <artifactId>downbox</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>downbox</name>
    <description>Downbox</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--This will make sure that you are using matching versions
            of the Hibernate OGM modules and their dependencies.-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring-Boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Mail-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Hibernate-OGM-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
            <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

while here is my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: downbox
      username: admin
      password: admin
      authentication-database: admin
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

This is the main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DownboxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DownboxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ant finally my entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "email")
    private Long id;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String object;
    private byte[] eml;
}
```

I'm stuck with this from a few days but not really understanding what's wrong here. Am I missing some dependency or some application property?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate OGM and Spring Data are two different libraries. I can see in the application.yml you are setting the properties for Spring Data but I don't see the configuration for Hibernate OGM (it's usually in the persistence.xml).
I don't think Hibernate OGM is starting.

Here's an example of a persistence.xml for OGM:

```
<persistence-unit name="hike-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="MONGODB" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="hike_db" />
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

It comes from this project demo: https://github.com/DavideD/hibernate-demos/tree/prova/hibernate-ogm/nosql-with-hibernate-ogm-101/hibernate-ogm-demo-nosql-with-hibernate-ogm-101-part-3